# Treating a class as a flag

Tags: c#, flags

Is it possible in C# to treat a class as a flag?
If I have class Foo

```
class Foo
{
// Do things...
}
```

and I have some variable (int or other), can I do something like this:

```
Foo test = new Foo();
Foo res = test | SOME_ENUM_FLAG | OTHER_FLAG;
```

and if so, how?

Comment: What.... are you trying to achieve here ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, I suggest you try to overload the `|` operator

```
class Foo
{
    public static Foo operator |(Foo left, Foo right) 
    {
       return new Foo(...);
    }

    // some more examples
    public static Foo operator |(Foo left, SomeEnum right) 
    {
       return new Foo(...);
    }

    public static Foo operator |(Foo left, int right) 
    {
       return new Foo(...);
    }
}
```

This can be as

```
Foo test = new Foo();
Foo res = test | SomeEnum.EnumValue | someInt;
```

or even

```
res |= SomeEnum.EnumValue
```

Comment: how it will help can you list an example

Comment: technically *overload*, but we know what you mean.

Comment: How operator overloading is helping OP's problem here , i want to learn this , please help

Comment: @Saurabh Well it doesn't actually 'treat the class as a flag'. It just allows you to use the same syntax as you would use with flags.

Comment: @p.s.w.g: Foo res = test | SOME_ENUM_FLAG | OTHER_FLAG; what i understood is '|' is used for bit wise OR operation , how come a class object and an Enum Value can be bit wise OR ed

Comment: @Saurabh when applied to integral data types, `|` represents the bitwise `OR` operator. When you overload it, it can mean (almost) anything you want. [Here's some recommended reading](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6fbs5e2h.aspx).

Comment: +1. @Saurabh, `|` is operation which simply have traditional meaning as "bitwise or", but nothing stops you from defining it as any other function for your own types. Coming up with strange/unconventional behavior for existing operators is generally bad idea (i.e. define "+" as "divide" for your own numerical type), but possible.

Answer (score 0):

Honestly, this is a bad idea.

It's going to reduce readability, introduce "fun" edge cases (I never thought someone would combine THOSE two...), etc.

If you want an enum, use an enum. If you want stateful behavior, use a class.

That said, if I **had** to do this, I would use a regular old enum for the combination part, and write extension methods to mimic methods and state.